# Ext Store proxy called too early

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an Ext/Sencha store proxy with a custom JSON reader. I noticed that the reader (hence, the proxy) is called way before it's used. The application launch process is like so:

- get geo location
- store it as global variable (namespaced)
- make AJAX call
- then create main view

**Problem**

I expect that the proxy isn't called before the main view (which adds a list which uses the store) is added. However, if the reader accesses the global geo variable set in the 2nd step very often it's null.

How can I work around that? The proxy must only be invoked once the geo location has been determined.

**app.js code fragments**

```
Ext.application({
  models: ['Station'],
  stores: ['Stations'],
  views: ['Main'],
  controllers: ['Application'],

  launch: function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
      ...
      listeners: {
        locationupdate: function (geo) {
          // store lat/long as global variables
          Ext.Ajax.request({
            ...
            success: function (response) {
              ...
              Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
              Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('APP.view.Main'));
            }
            ...
    }).updateLocation();
```

**app/store/Stations.js**

```
Ext.define('SunApp.store.Stations', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: ['SunApp.store.StationReader'],

  config: {
    autoLoad: true,
    ...
    proxy: {
      ...
      reader: {
        type: 'stationReader'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**app/store/StationReader.js**

```
Ext.define('SunApp.store.StationReader', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.reader.Json',
  alias: 'reader.stationReader',

  getResponseData: function (response) {
    var data = this.callParent([response]);
    return this.filter(data);
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `autoLoad` property for store to `false`, and then load it manually.

Comment: This did occur to me, too. However, where would I create and load the store? Right now my main view has `items:[{xtype:'stations'}]` and the `stations` view simply declares `config:{store:'Stations',...`. So, somehow I'd have to use `Ext.create` to create my store, load it and then I'd have to set this store instance to the `stations` view which in turn isn't created manually. Obviously I'm still confused about the Sencha Touch application wiring.

Comment: Do you have file with store class definition? `autoLoad` would go there. So you don't need to create it - it will be created automatically. You just need to load it when it's necessary according to your logic.

Comment: Yes, that much I understood, just wasn't sure to get a hold of the store. Now also added the store and reader code fragments to the question for sake of completeness. I set `autoLoad: false` in the store and invoked `Ext.getStore('Stations').load()` in `app.js` just before `Ext.fly`. This seems to work fine. Thanks.

Comment: There you go. The store object is static and one per store per application. So whenever you do Ext.getStore() you just that store instance. And you can do with it whatever you want.